# How to parse integer command line arguments in C?

Tags: c, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I would like a user to pass either two parameters or leave it blank. For instance:

```
./program 50 50
```

or

```
./program
```

When I tried to use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, first thing I have done was to change `char *argv[]` to `int *argv[]` but it did not work. What I want is from the user is just **to enter two integers between 0 and 100**. So if it is not two integers then it should give an error.

I was sort of thinking to give out an error with types (as I used to program on C#) but whatever I enter, argv[1] would be 'char' type all the time.

So what I have done is

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    //printf("%d", i);
    if (argv[1] == i) {
        argcheck++;
        printf("1st one %d\n", i);
    }
    else if (argv[2] == i) {
        argcheck++;
        printf("2nd one %d\n", i);
    }
```

This does not work as well. Also it gives warning when compiling, but if I change `argv` with `atoi(argv[1])` for instance, then it gives a *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* error.

I need a simple way to solve this problem.

EDIT:

So I fixed with `atoi()`, the reason why it was giving segmentation fault was because I was trying it with null value when I have no parameter. So I fixed it up by adding an extra cond. But now the problem is if the value is let's say

```
./program asd asd
```

Then the output of `atoi(argv[1])` would be 0. Is there a way to change this value?

Comment: Please post your edit as a separate question. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: Before calling atoi, check that the string you are passing is an integer. Use a loop and isdigit() from ctype.h.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't use `atoi()` and don't use `strtol()`. `atoi()` has no error checking (as you found out!) and `strtol()` has to be error-checked using the global `errno` variable, which means you have to set `errno` to 0, then call `strtol()`, then check `errno` again for errors. **A better way is to use `sscanf()`**, which also lets you parse any primitive type from a string, not just an integer, and it lets you read fancy formats (like hex).

For example, to parse integer "1435" from a string:

```
if (sscanf (argv[1], "%i", &intvar) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error - not an integer");
}
```

To parse a single character 'Z' from a string

```
if (sscanf (argv[1], "%c", &charvar)!=1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error - not a char");
}
```

To parse a float "3.1459" from a string

```
if (sscanf (argv[1], "%f", &floatvar)!=1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error - not a float");
}
```

To parse a large unsigned hexadecimal integer "0x332561" from a string

```
if (sscanf (argv[1], "%xu", &uintvar)!=1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error - not a hex integer");
}
```

If you need more error-handling than that, use a regex library.

Comment: You can use `strtol()`'s second argument (the end-pointer) to error-check without involving `errno`.

Comment: You can indeed use the second argument to strtol() to check for all errors that are not valid 0l, overflow or underflow, meaning you still have to check errno for over/underflow.

Comment: Erm? `sscanf` is just as bad itt can't detect overflow. If the scanned integer value can't git, it's undefined behaviour. While you *can* specify widths in the format string, you still need to know the range of the integers, it doesn't get any easier than strtol (you need to know the platform's INT_MAX format example and decide to specify a closest approximation as the width in the format string accordingly). So `strto[u]*` functions are actually the better option, more so for user-supplied inputs.

Comment: 1. There is no overflow in sscanf()ing an integer. 2. If the input cannot be scanned there is no undefined behaviour because you can check the return from scanf in the same line that it is invoked. 3. You don't need to use INT_MAX. 4. the strto() group of functions need two separate statements to check for errors, hence most uses of it don't check for errors.

Comment: @Lelanthran If input is too large, sscanf'ing will overflow. The return value check isn't useful because, if input can't be represented, overflow already happened. See: https://www.onlinegdb.com/SJ5VOuOIN

Comment: @P.P. That's not a scanf buffer overflow, it's an integer overflow and the same integer overflow (which is UB) happens with strtol functions. See: https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/SJ5VOuOIN

Comment: @Lelanthran I didn't say it's buffer overflow. Except that `strto*` functions can detect integer overflows *without resuling in UB*. That's precisely why they're better for unchecked user inputs. I am not sure what I am supposed to see in that link, given that I originally posted it.

Comment: @P.P. Sorry, wrong link; I forked it and didn't realise that the url remained the same. While the strtol functions do indeed report an error on integer overflow, they still overflow. The **same** UB is there in both sscanf as well as strol functions.

Comment: @Lelanthran "While the strtol functions do indeed report an error on integer overflow, they still overflow." - No, they do **not** overflow; they  return the respective  `*_MAX` value for the type (e.g., `LONG_MAX` for `strtol`) and set errno indicating that *if* the given string is converted to integer, then it would overflow. Whereas in the case of *scanf functions, it the given value can't be represented, it'll overflow and results in undefined behaviour (which isn't the case with strto* functions).

Answer (score 14):

This will do:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
   long a,b;
   if (argc > 2) 
   {
      a = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
      b = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
      printf("%ld %ld", a,b);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The arguments are always passed as strings, you can't change the prototype of `main()`. The operating system and surrounding machinery always pass strings, and are not able to figure out that you've changed it.

You need to use e.g. `strtol()` to convert the strings to integers.

Answer (score 2):

You want to check whether

1. 0 or 2 argument is received
2. two values received are between 0 and 100
3. received argument is not a string. If string comes `sscanf` will return
   0.

Below logic will helps you

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int no1 = 0, no2 = 0, ret = 0;

    if ((argc != 0) && (argc != 2)) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (2 == argc)
    {
        ret = sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &no1);
        if (ret != 1)return 0;
        ret = sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &no2);
        if (ret != 1)return 0;          

        if ((no1 < 0) || (no1 >100)) return 0;
        if ((no2 < 0) || (no2 >100)) return 0;          
    }

    //now do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The things you have done so innocently are blunder in C. No matter what, you have to take strings or chars as your arguments and then later you can do whatever you like with them. Either change them to integer using `strtol` or let them be the strings and check each char of the string in the range of `48 to 57` as these are the decimal values of `char 0 to 9`. Personally, this is not a good idea and not so good coding practice. Better convert them and check for the integer range you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can **still** use **atoi**, just check whether the argument is a number first ;)
*btw ppl will tell you goto is* **evil**, *but they're usually brainwashed by non-sensible* **"goto is bad"**, **"goto is evil"**, **"goto is the devil"** *statements that were just tossed out without elaboration on the internet.*
Yes, spaggethi code is less managable. And goto in that context is from an age where it replaced functions...

```
    int r, n, I;
    for (I = 0; I < argc; ++I)
    {
      n = 0;
      do
        if ( !((argv + I) [n] >= '0' && (argv + I) [n] <= '9') )
        {
          err:
            fprintf(stderr,"ONLY INTEGERS 0-100 ALLOWED AS ARGUMENTS!\n");
            return 1;
        }
      while ((argv + I) [++n] != '\0')
      r = atoi(argv[I]);
      if (r > 100)
        goto err;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not change the arguments of main() function. So you should just use atoi() function to convert arguments from string to integer.

atoi() has its drawbacks. Same is true for strtol() or strtoul() functions. These functions will return a 0 value if the input to the function is non-numeric i.e user enters asdf or anything other than a valid number. To overcome this you will need to parse the string before passing it to atoi() and call [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/) on each character to make sure that the user has input a valid number. After that you can use atoi() to convert to integer.

Comment: atoi() function causes Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: @SarpKaya I have added more about atoi() to my answer. Plz take a look.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main(int argc,char *args[])
{
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<=argc;i++)
    {
        printf("\n The %d argument is: %s",i,args[i]);
    }
    printf("\nTHe sum of given argumnets are:");
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
       int n;
       n=atoi(args[i]);
       printf("\nN=%d",n);
       sum += n;
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of given numbers are %d",sum);
    return(0);

  }
```

check this program i added another library stdlib.h and so i can convert the character array to string using function atoi.