# how would I pass a specific type of number in the command line?

Tags: c, command-line, integer

I understand how to pass an integer through the command line, but how would I do this if I needed a specific range of integers?

For example I have a program that accepts a range of numbers and divides them by five. The number needs to be within 30-105, and must be a multiple of 5.

And if any number out of that range and is not a multiple of 5, there would be an error message.

How can I do this?

Comment: You pass strings (that represent the integers -- you can only really pass strings)...  and you get the integer values from the strings... and you check that they're in the range you want... and if not, you print an error message.  Which part are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: `if(!(30 <= number && number <= 105 && number % 5 == 0)) puts("error");`

Comment: @Dmitri The check if they're in the range part. If it does print an error, how does it go back to prompting the command line to enter another number?

Comment: This post will show you how to check if passed in parameters are valid ints, but your own code needs to check on the range and report the error to the user. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12092545/6693299

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Would I have to use a while loop in order for it to go back to the command line if given the error message?

Comment: Command line arguments can not be re-entered during execution. Simply exit the program after displaying the error or let enter an alternative numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to do three things:

1. Get all numbers from the command line
2. Check if they're valid
3. Print an error message if necessary

Let's get number 2 out of the way first, checking the validity.

```
bool isValid(int number) {
    return (number >= 30 && number <= 105 && number % 5 == 0);
}
```

This function checks if the given number fits your criteria; greater than or equal to 30, lesser than or equal to 105, and divisible by 5. Now, we have to use that function to validate the arguments.

To do that, we have to loop over all of them and check if they are valid, aborting on the first error.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i != argc; ++i) {
        int number = atoi(argv[i]);
        if (!isValid(number)) {
            puts("Error!");
            break;
        } else {
            // do something
         }
     }
}
```

If you want to keep the valid numbers, you'd have to store them in an array in the `else`-branch.

**Edit:**
Reading your comments made me think you don't want to get the numbers from the actual command line (as in `./myProgram 30 40 50`) but from a prompt in the program itself.

Getting a single number at a time, we have to:

1. Print a prompt
2. Read a number
3. Check if it's valid

We can isolate that in a function, but to keep it short, I'll not do that and shamelessly put it in `main`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;

    while (true) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if (isValid(number)) {
            break;
        } else {
            puts("Not a valid number!");
        }
    }

    // do something
}
```

Comment: Would this have to be a while loop in order for the command line to be prompted again for another chance at checking the "right" type of number?

Comment: The command line cannot be prompted; everything in `argv` is fixed at startup. If you want to have the user enter another number, you'd need to read it from stdin using `scanf` for example.

Comment: If you are using `bool`, then you need to define it as it is not a standard type.